# Submitting form to different actions in CakePHP 2.6 results in blackhole

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I've got a form in my CakePHP 2.6 app which has multiple buttons to submit the form to different actions. With Cake 2.4, this worked, but on 2.6 submitting to anything other than the default form action leads to a blackhole `'auth'` error.

Just before the end of my form, I have multiple submit buttons, like so:

```
echo $this->Form->button('Default', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
));
echo $this->Form->button('Alternate 1', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'formaction' => '/posts/otheraction',
)); 
echo $this->Form->button('Alernate 2', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'formaction' => '/posts/anotheraction',
));
```

[Reading the docs,](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) I see `‘auth’ Indicates a form validation error, or a controller/action mismatch error.`. However, this worked in the past- it seems like things have gotten stricter. How can you get Cake to accept submitted forms from other actions without turning off Security completely?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem to be possible (at least not without jumping through enourmously large hoops), as the action is being incorporated in the token unconditionally.

```
$hashParts = array(
    $this->_lastAction, // <<<<<<<<<<<
    serialize($fields),
    $unlocked,
    Configure::read('Security.salt')
);
$fields = Security::hash(implode('', $hashParts), 'sha1');
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.1/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L589**

Also disabling this behavior would possibly weaken security, as posting to actions the data wasn't ment to be used for, might cause unintended behaviour.

You can handle this with a single action though, for example by giving the various submit buttons a name and a value, and in your controller action evaluate the value and do whatever needs to be done

```
echo $this->Form->button('Default', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'name' => 'action',
    'value' => 'default'
));
echo $this->Form->button('Alternate 1', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'name' => 'action',
    'value' => 'alternate1'
)); 
echo $this->Form->button('Alernate 2', array(
    'type' => 'submit',
    'name' => 'action',
    'value' => 'alternate2'
));
```

```
switch ($this->request->data('action')) {
    case 'default':
        // ...
        break;

    case 'alternate1':
        // ...
        break;

    case 'alternate2':
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to change the form's action

HTML button:

```
<button id='saveSubmitter'>Save</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('body').on('click', '#saveSubmitter',
  function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      $('form').attr('action', '<?php echo Router::url( array("action"=>"save")); ?>')
      $('form').submit()
  }
)
```